# group a list by key and identify new and expired elements between groups

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a set of data that looks like:

```
<date>,<id>
24-01-2017,1
24-01-2017,2
24-01-2017,3
25-01-2017,1
25-01-2017,4
26-01-2017,1
```

I want to group the data by date and count the number of new IDs that appeared in each date, and the number of previously existing IDs that was removed.

So for the example, I am expecting an output that looks like:

```
<date>,<new_IDs>,<removed_IDs>
24-01-2017,0,0
25-01-2017,1,2
26-01-2017,0,1
```

I am trying to do this efficiently in Spark and cannot think of an easy way (well, I thought of cartesian, but it seems really silly). Any help is appreciated, thanks.

==========EDIT=========

I can currently do it by collecting everything to the Master:

i.e.:

```
val part1 = data.groupByKey.collect.sortBy(_._1).dropRight(1)
val part2 = data.groupByKey.collect.sortBy(_._1).drop(1)
val result = (part1,part2).zipped.map((x,y)=>(y._1,((x._2 diff y._2).size , (y._2 diff x._2).size)))
```

I would prefer a method that is parallelized.

Comment: show some code...

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need cartesian. Let's assume the days are sequential (i.e. you always know what the previous day is by calculating a single way back. If this is not the case you can index them to find the previous index).

You can now do a groupby on the date and collect_list to get the ids. then use date_sub to subtract one day as a new column.

Now do a join between the two so you would have for each date also the previous date and do a UDF to calculate the differencse.

If after the groupby your data is small enough you can try using a window with only an orderBy (no partitionBy) and use the lag function